# Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, pakistani-citizens, greece

Nationality =Pakistan
Resident -Turkey

Applied from istanbul with family

Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided